# Выборка последних записей из связанной таблицы

Tags: mysql

Есть две таблицы в одной список пользователей, а в другой некоторые данные по каждому пользователю, которые заносятся периодически, совершенно по разному для каждого пользователя. Как выбрать из двух таблиц: из таблицы пользователей и из связанной таблицы самую последнюю связанную  запись для каждого пользователя (сортировка по дате добавления)? Или второй вариант решения - заносить данные сразу в две таблицы - в строчку пользователя(update) и в связанную таблицу(insert)? Так у меня свежие данные будут в самой таблице пользователей и отдельная таблица с историей изменений. Как оптимальнее будет?

Comment: Накидал пример в sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4be63/1  ... оно?

Answer (score 2):

Может быть будет верно))
Таблица `users` и `user_records` с записями юзеров, связанная с юзерами через `user_id`

```
SELECT u.id, u.`name`, (
    SELECT `record` 
    FROM user_records 
    WHERE user_id = ur.`user_id` 
    ORDER BY `datetime` DESC 
    LIMIT 1) AS `last_record`
FROM users u
left JOIN user_records ur
ON u.`id` = ur.`user_id`
GROUP BY u.id
```

Как тест http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4be63/2

Answer (score 2):

Поиск последней записи будем делать по полю `date` в котором лежит дата добавления записи в данные пользователя `user_data`. Так же можно использовать ID записи из `user_data` если там есть такое поле.

```
select *
  from users U
  left join user_data D
         on D.user_id=U.user_id
        and D.date=(select date from user_data D1
                     where D1.user_id=U.user_id
                     order by date desc limit 1
                   )
```

В принципе получение данных непосредственно из таблицы пользователей было бы быстрее, если бы мы туда заносили эти самые последние данные. Но это вносит излишнюю избыточность в БД, т.е. в принципе ради производительности, если будут замечены проблемы с вышеописанным запросом на это можно пойти. Но любая избыточность порождает более медленное обновление данных и возможные ошибки вроде такой что в user_data запись вставили, а в users обновить забыли. Или из user_data удаляем последнюю, ошибочно добавленную запись, как обновить данные в users - правильно, найдя более старую запись, примерно таким же запросом, как приведен выше...

Comment: Хм.... а у меня оболочка ругалась на неверный синтаксис, когда я пытался `select.....order by date desc` записать в условие `join` ..... поэтому пришлось через групп делать и выносить подзапрос наверх...... хмм......наверное оболочка тупила

Comment: @АлексейШиманский А может вы писали не `date=(...)`, а `date in(...)` ? MySQL не позволяет использовать `limit` внутри подзапроса `in`, а в случае обычного "равно" позволяет :)

Comment: неее. про `IN` даже не вспоминал ни разу, да он тут как бэ и не к месту) ....ну ладно, спишем все на полуночные глюки

Comment: Согласен насчет избыточности. Я использую транзакции для таких "парных" обновлений-добавлений. Удаляться данные из таблицы истории не будут. Наверное все же сделаю добавляя-изменяя в обе таблицы но потестирую запросы, что предложил, опыт у меня небольшой но эти вещи жутко интересны. Задача у меня специфическая. Такой себе "минибанк". Узкий круг пользователей и небольшое количество операций.

Comment: @АртемТихонович По хорошему триггер на user_data делаете, он при вставке сам обновляет user

Comment: @Mike Триггер  - так же надежен как транзакции? У меня база mysql с InnoDb engine.

Comment: @АртемТихонович InnoDB все делает в транзакции, даже если вы ее не начинаете явно. (неявная транзакция коммитится при успешном завершении запроса) И триггер выполняется в той же транзакции, что и основной SQL-запрос. Так что да, надежен

Answer (score 1):

Пусть имеется таблица `users` с пользователями и связанная с ней через внешний ключ `user_id` таблица `tbl`. Пусть дата обновления хранится в поле `tbl.updated_at`. Тогда получить пользователей и соответствующие им последние записи из таблицы `tbl` можно при помощи следующего запроса

```
SELECT
  u.*, t1.*
FROM
  users AS u
LEFT JOIN
  tbl AS t1
ON
  u.id = t1.user_id 
LEFT JOIN
  tbl AS t2
ON
  u.id = t2.user_id AND
  t1.updated_at < t2.updated_at 
WHERE
  t2.updated_at IS NULL
```

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую. Результат мне нужен таблица пользователей с дополнительными полями в которых данные самой свежей записи из связанной таблицы.Если там нет записей связанных то поля эти будут NULL. Но запись пользователя нужна в любом случае.

Comment: Тогда LEFT JOIN - это именно то, что вам нужно, все записи из левой таблицы присутствуют не зависимо от того, есть связь или нет. Если связи нет - выдается NULL.

Comment: Да именно так. Спасибо большое. Для меня пока не знакома конструкция ON...AND..это наверное и есть сортировка новой записи я так понял.

Comment: Не совсем. При помощи ON связываются две таблицы. Так как мы имеем дело с множествами, чтобы отсортировать таблицы в нужном нам порядке мы прибегаем к самообъединению таблиц, два раза соединяем таблицу tbl (назначая ей разные названия при помощи AS). Условие t1.updated_at < t2.updated_at позволяет выбрать нам последние записи из таблицы t2.