# Выбрать последние записи из топиков

Tags: mysql, sql

имеется таблица, примерно такая

```
CREATE TABLE messages_list (
    id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    tstamp int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    recipient_id int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    sender_id int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    content tinytext,
    topic_id int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

В ней хранятся сообщения из разных топиков(topic_id). Нужно выбрать последние сообщения из каждого топика.

```
`SELECT max(id) FROM `messages_list` group by topic_id`
```

- таким запросом можно выбрать id последних записей, а как изменить запрос, чтобы получить всю информацию?

Comment: Нужно сгруппировать по topic_id

Comment: `SELECT * FROM messages_list group by topic_id order by tstamp DESC` такой запрос возвращает первые сообщения из топиков

Comment: их может быть неограниченное количество

Comment: Вы хотите в разнобой или по конкретным топикам? Или достаточно выбрать первые 10..100 id-шников и отсортировать по топикам?

Comment: Допустим у меня в таблице 200 сообщений, которые относятся к 20 топикам, так вот, я хочу получить из всех топиков по одному последнему сообщению, то есть 20 сообщений

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/516129/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B/516179#516179  Очень похоже ...

Comment: там все же другое немного, две базы и джоины...

Comment: Смысл тот же. подзапросом к той же таблице получате последние даты в разрезе топиков. у вас так совсем просто: `select * from table where id in(select max(id) from table group by topic_id)`

Comment: ... Допустим у меня в таблице... -  так ваш запрос (в вопросе внизу) верный, чем он вам не нравится?

Comment: @Mike, спасибо, я попытался через вложенный запрос, но Max вынес во внешний, поэтому у меня не получалось

Comment: Ладно, напишу ответом, хотя наверняка где то уже есть с десяток подобных ответов. тяжело дубли вопросов по SQL искать ... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM `messages_list`
 WHERE id IN(
         SELECT max(id) FROM `messages_list` group by topic_id
       )
```