# SQL group by nonaggregated columns

Tags: sql, group-by

i have a table/у меня есть таблица:
id_msg - int(255) autoincrement 
id_user - varchar(255)
chat_id -varchar(255)
msg - text
ava_img - varchar(500)
first_name- varchar(500)
time_of_msg -timestamp [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP]

i need for select all columns without reiteration on chat_id/ мне необходимо получить все строки(с выводом всех полей) но без повторений значения поля chat_id, при использовании group by получаю ошибку о неагрегирущих данных

```
SELECT * FROM in_msg GROUP BY chat_id HAVING count(DISTINCT chat_id) > 1
```

Comment: А зачем вы выбираете `*` т.е. все поля таблицы ? вам надо решить какие поля вам действительно нужны и какие значения показать для полей, не участвующих в group by, т.е. применить к ним функции max/min/sum

Comment: Так не бывает. Что значит без повтора chat_id? Если у вас один и тот же chat_id но с разными id_user - что вы ждете увидеть на выходе?

Comment: И если вы делаете gorup by chat_id, то у вас в каждой строке результата будет ровно 1 chat_id и следовательно условие having count(distinct chat_id)>1 всегда будет ложно

Comment: например у меня есть 8 записей в таблице, в них чат айди повторяется 3 раза, т.е. мне надо получить 3 строки со всеми columns

Comment: отлично, у вас есть одна строка с chat_id=1 и msg="ABC" И вторая строка chat_id=1 и msg="XYZ". На выходе вы хотите получить одну строку chat_id=1, но что при этом должно быть отражено в поле msg ?

Comment: в идеале мне нужна была последнея строка по времени time_of_msg, остальные строки отправленые в бд ранее исключить

Comment: тогда что то в этом роде http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562926/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2/562937#562937

Comment: или такое http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496515/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC (только mysql). вы кстати не указали какая у вас БД

Comment: да, MySQL, спасибо за отзывчивость и помощь , сейчас попробую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * 
from table a
inner join (
    select chat_id ,count(*)
    from table 
    group  by chat_id 
    having count(*) > 1
) b on a.chat_id = b.chat_id
```