# Сортировка внутри группировки

Tags: mysql

Таблица

```
id | usr | how | dt
-----------------------------
1  | 101 | 10  | 2016-10-16
-----------------------------
2  | 101 | 20  | 2016-10-16
-----------------------------
3  | 101 | 30  | 2016-10-17
```

Нужно сделать такой запрос:

```
SELECT id,how, MONTH(dt) AS `dt` FROM stat WHERE usr = '101' GROUP BY YEAR(dt), MONTH(dt)
```

Но выдаёт в группировке первые строки, типа id 1, а по сути надо id 3. `ORDER BY id DESC` не помогает

Пробовал так, но тоже нет

```
SELECT * from ( SELECT id,how, MONTH(dt) AS `dt` FROM stat WHERE usr = '101' ORDER BY id DESC) AS te GROUP BY YEAR(te.dt), MONTH(te.dt) ORDER BY te.id DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Большинство СУБД (и MySQL при включенной опции only_full_group_by) вообще бы выдали вам ошибку на такой запрос. Потому, что использовать в выводе колонки без групповых функций, не включенные в фразу group by нельзя (в MySQL можно, но результат непредсказуем). Необходимо явно объяснить SQL какое значение из нескольких в группе вы хотите получить.

Используйте агрегатные функции, например:

```
SELECT max(id) as id, max(how) as how, MONTH(dt) AS `dt`
  FROM stat WHERE usr = 101
 GROUP BY YEAR(dt), MONTH(dt)
```

А для получения последних (по id) записей каждого месяца можно сделать так:

```
select *
  from table A
  join (select max(id) from table where usr=101
         group by extract(year_month from dt)) B
    on A.id=B.id
```

А что касается предварительной сортировки строк перед группировкой, то она смысла не имеет, потому как group by сам выполняет сортировку в собственном порядке и не обращает ни малейшего внимания на предыдущий порядок строк.

Comment: id выдаёт верно, а данные с первой строки типа 3 | 10 | 10

Comment: @Rammsteinik Может вам нужна именно последняя строка каждого месяца, так таких вопросов-ответов 2-3 в месяц. например http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562926/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2/562937#562937

Comment: верно, попробую