# Помогите оптимизировать MySQL запрос к нескольким таблицам с большим количеством записей

Tags: php, mysql

Друзья, помогите правильно сформировать оптимальный запрос к MYSQL базе.
Суть следующая

1. Есть таблица устройств, в которой порядка 100-200 записей.
2. Есть таблицы 2 и 3 с характеристиками работы устройств во времени. То есть, для каждого устройства с определенным интервалом в обе таблицы делается запись. В каждой таблице порядка 1 миллиона записей.
3. На текущий момент php скрипт обходит по очереди все устройства по списку в таблице 1 и для каждого устройства выбирает таблиц 2 и 3 самую последнюю по времени запись.

   Проблема в том, что, на выполнение этой операции по всем устройствам уходит почти 2 минуты.
   Подскажите, как это можно сделать оптимальнее.
   Таблицы связаны следующим образом - для каждой записи в таблицах 2 и 3 есть столбец DeviceID, соотвествующий столбцу ID в таблице 1.
   Время по каждой записи храниться в формате DATETIME.

Сейчас запросы имеют вид:

```
SELECT * FROM таблица 1
```

Потом в цикле for по записям из таблицы 1:

```
SELECT * FROM таблица 2 WHERE DeviceID = таблица1.ID
ORDER BY DATETIME DESC LIMIT 1
```

То же самое - по таблице 3

Comment: А сами запросы sql как сейчас выглядят?

Comment: чуть больше конкретики - какие данные Вам нужно получать из таблиц 2 и 3? и еще неплохо бы структуру таблиц дать: необходимые поля + имеющиеся по ним индексы.

Comment: Да, дайте точную структуру таблиц, какие индексы на них сейчас построены, пример данных в таблицах и желаемый результат. Так же посмотрите похожие вопросы, возможно там уже содержится нужный вам ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/516129/194569

Comment: у зачем проходить по всем устройствам? JOIN вы используете?

Comment: Таблицы 2 и 3 содержат данные опросов устройств с интервалом 10 мин. Грубо - по 10 полей типа int. Именно эти данные мне и нужно получать. 

Сейчас запросы имеют вид:
SELECT * FROM таблица 1
Потом в цикле for по записям из таблицы 1:

SELECT * FROM таблица 2 WHERE DeviceID = таблица1.ID ORDER BY DATETIME DESC LIMIT 1
То же самое - по таблице 3

Comment: @Jean-Claude 
Не использую Потому и спрашиваю, каким образом лучше сформулировать запрос, чтобы ускорить процесс.

Answer (score 0):

Это называется денормализация данных. В таблице 1 создаете столбцы из таблиц 2 и 3 по которым вам надо выводить данные. При записи данные пишите сразу в таблицы 2 и 3 через INSERT и в созданные столбцы таблицы 1 выполняете UPDATE (записываете последние по времени данные).

Далее все просто, выполняете SELECT в таблицу 1 и выводите необходимые данные. Запрос по времени порядка 0.00005 сек.

Comment: Не выйдет. В таблице 1 просто перечень устройств. Мне не нужно туда запихивать все данные по опросам устройств.

Answer (score 0):

Подзапросы в центре достанут последние даты и значениями измерений по устройствам из таблиц с измерениями(measurement1-2). Join результатов подзапросов(derived1-2) с таблицей устройств(device) сделает всё остальное.

```
SELECT 
  device.id,
  device.name,
  derived1.measurement_time,
  derived1.value,
  derived2.measurement_time,
  derived2.value,
FROM device
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    measurement1.device_id,
    measurement1.value, 
    MAX(measurement1.time) as measurement_time
  FROM measurement1
  GROUP BY measurement1.device_id ) derived1 ON
    derived1.device_id = device.id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    measurement2.device_id,
    measurement2.value,
    MAX(measurement2.time) as measurement_time
  FROM measurement2
  GROUP BY measurement1.device_id ) derived2 ON
    derived2.device_id = device.id
```